# Issue with Import/Export Timeline record on chrome dev tool

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, timeline, web-performance

I recorded a scenario in Chrome Developer Tools, Timeline. I "save/export" the timeline to my computer, BUT i saw that the file is with 0 bytes (means that nothing is saved ). 
After that when i try to import the file i get an exception, regard to incorrect JSON format.

How can i save the timeline and after that import it in chrome dev tools?

Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you "importing" into DevTools? As far as I know that currently is not supported in any way. Did you double-check the actual file saved? I typically see the 0 bytes thing, but upon checking the file it is fully populated with the data.

Comment: hi, i just right click on timeline and i have option for export/import file. BTW in my "export" file i have 0 byte Without any data inside it.... Strange...

Comment: Can you go to `chrome://version` please and get the Google Chrome and Revision version information? Export is working fine in Canary.  P.S. Good catch on the import (Load), I never noticed it before even though it is surely there.

Comment: @Garbee - Google Chrome 47.0.2526.73 (Official Build) m (32-bit)
Revision 9a9ccd65b451d3e6098e7d2632befae54e596791-refs/branch-heads/2526@{#471}